# PHP strstr() returns only one line

Tags: php, multiline, strstr

first of all: I really love this site and I think this is the best forum for programming :)

Now to my problem, which I try to display using code and comments:

```php
    $file = fopen ($URL, "r");
    // $URL is a string set before, which is correct
    // Also, I got the page-owners permission to acquire the page like that
    if (!$file) 
    {
        echo "<p>Could not open file.\n";
        exit;
    }
    while (!feof ($file)) 
    {
        $buffer = fgets($file);
        $buffer= strstr($buffer, "Montag</b>"); 
        // If I don't use this line, the whole page gets displayed...
        // If I use this line, only the first line after the needle gets displayed
        echo $buffer;
    }
    fclose($file);
```

So basically, I'm able to display the whole page, or one line after the needle, but not everything after the needle....

I tried to find a solution using the PHP Reference, the Stackoverflow Search engine and of course google, but I couldn't find a solution, thanks for everybody willing to help me.

Greetings userrr3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Extracting text from the file

You are only grabbing one line at a time from the file using [`fgets()` <sup>DOCs</sup>](http://php.net/fgets) if you want the whole file then use [`file_get_contents()` <sup>DOCs</sup>](http://php.net/file_get_contents) instead:

```
$file = file_get_contents($URL);
$buffer= strstr($file, "Montag</b>"); 
// If I don't use this line, the whole page gets displayed...
// If I use this line, only the first line after the needle gets displayed
echo $buffer;
```

### Grabbing your text

This can be achieved using PHPs [`substr()` <sup>DOCs</sup>](http://php.net/substr) function combined with [`strpos()` <sup>DOCs</sup>](http://php.net/strpos):

```
$buffer = substr($buffer, strpos($buffer, 'Montag</b>'));
```

This will grab all the text after the first occurrence of the needle `Montag</b>`.

### Putting it all together

```
$file = file_get_contents($URL);
$buffer = substr($file, strpos($buffer, 'Montag</b>'));
echo $buffer;
```

Comment: This works perfectly, except $file has to be replaced by $buffer. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Good catch. I have updated my answer under `Putting it all together` to fix this :)